# MySQLWorkbench Connection Problems

Tags: mysql

I have problems connecting to my MySQL server using MySQLWorkbench.  I believe it's some type of permissions issue, to ensure I am able to use this, can you help me with the necessary setup steps?  I have done the following:

- Setup a user called 'root' which can be connected to through any IP (*)
- Tried to use SSH and direct connections in MySQLWorkbench
- Actually, I have tried every setting and combination in sql workbench

Here's the things I would like to do/learn in sql workbench:

- Restore Backups
- From the admin page, watch the 'System' graphs and monitor the server. The things the cool kids can do.
- Add/edit user accounts, change passwords for accounts (even root) without going to commandline
- Actually, do EVERYTHING administratively without the command line.  The mysql commandline is about the least enjoyable thing I ever have to mess with.

Can you give me any idea how to get this thing setup?  I am using Ubuntu 10.x on the server with MySQL 5.1.x - everything works great except for connecting by MySQLWorkbench.  I am connecting remotely, but I have a fast internet connection and my server is on rackspace.

Thanks for your help!

Br

Answer (score 2):

First things first! :P

Can you open a telnet connection against your MySQL box on the mysql port (telnet [ip_of_the_box] 3306)?

If this doesn't work, you need to check firewalls and your connectivity to the mysql server on port 3306.

Also, looks like the syntax of your *"Setup a user called 'root' which can be connected to through any IP (*)"* is wrong... The user should be able to connect from % and not *. (In SQL Syntax % means all not *).

MySQL Workbench is pretty easy to deal with... Check the two things above and see if it work . After you can connect you will be able to do all the things that you asked without too much trouble.